# How can we configure paths for .cshrc

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, tcsh, csh

Within a shell script, i am trying to open a new tcsh shell and load some set of pre defined aliases and env variables which i do not want to have in default cshrc. I cannot have it in my home dir also as this script is  going to be used by multiple users.
What are the paths tcsh will look for cshrc file when a new xterm or shell is created? Is it configurable through some env variable?

Answer (score 1):

From [the manpage](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Startup_and_shutdown.html):

> A login shell begins by executing commands from the system files
>   /etc/csh.cshrc and /etc/csh.login. It then executes commands from
>   files in the user's home directory: first ~/.tcshrc (+) or, if
>   ~/.tcshrc is not found, ~/.cshrc, then ~/.history (or the value of the
>   histfile shell variable), then ~/.login, and finally ~/.cshdirs (or
>   the value of the dirsfile shell variable) (+). The shell may read
>   /etc/csh.login before instead of after /etc/csh.cshrc, and ~/.login
>   before instead of after ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc and ~/.history, if so
>   compiled; see the version shell variable. (+)

There is no argument of environment variable to change this, except for `-f` to prevent loading a startup file.

You can use the `source` command to load a file from within `tcsh`, though:

```
source /etc/my-special-settings.tcsh
```

You could also do something like this in your user's `~/.tcshrc`:

```
if ( $?SPECIAL_SETTINGS ) then
    source /etc/my-special-settings.tcsh
else
    source ~/.tcsh/tcshrc
endif
```

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker, i am indeed using env variable approach. I did not want to ask all users to add this to their .cshrc.